# Avoid loading XHR data each time

Tags: javascript, promise, xmlhttprequest, fetch, autosuggest

I want to create a form with two fields. One is the starting station and the other is the ending station. The stations are stored in a JSON file `{[],[],[]}` This json file is about 400KB in size. I want to initialise the stations only once and use them for both input fields. But I can't do that. So I rewrote it so that it loads the JSON as soon as you focus on an input field. Which is pretty stupid. I would be really happy about help.  This is my current structure:

**app.js**

```
// load own suggestion script
import suggestion from './suggestion';

document.getElementById('from').addEventListener('focus', function() {
    suggestion.start('from')
});

document.getElementById('to').addEventListener('focus', function() {
    suggestion.start('to')
});
```

**suggestion.js**

```
export default {
    stations: [],
    formSelector: '',
    url: 'http://localhost:8090/api.php',
    getData() {
        fetch(this.url)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => { 
                // call the autocomplete function and pass the stationData               
                this.autocomplete(document.getElementById(this.formSelector), data)
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err)
            });
    },
    autocomplete(inp, arr) {
        // some code ... this code fetch the input value and iterate the stations object and create a suggestionlist. I have shortened it for this question.
    },
    start(selector) {
        this.formSelector = selector;
        this.getData();
    }
}
```

**html**

```
<span>from</span>
<input id="from" type="text" placeholder="Station from">

<span>to</span>
<input id="to" type="text" placeholder="Station to">
```

Comment: Perhaps [pagination](https://www.google.com/search?q=autocomplete+%28paging+OR+pagination%29+site%3Astackoverflow.com) or fetch only stuff with the first letters typed

Comment: @mplungjan thank you! you can probably change something in the structure so that it only loads the data once. However, this is where I run into the promise "problem".

Answer (score 0):

How is the following?
Is it what you want to do?

```
getData() {
    if( this.stations ) {
        this.autocomplete(document.getElementById(this.formSelector), this.stations);
    } else {
        fetch(this.url)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => { 
                // call the autocomplete function and pass the stationData               
                this.stations = data;
                this.autocomplete(document.getElementById(this.formSelector), this.stations);                    
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err)
            });
    }
},
```